# Redis + .NET 6 - Best data type for querying all entries and updating individual entries

Tags: redis, .net-6.0, spring-data-redis

I recently got to know Redis, integrated it into my project and now I am facing the following use case.

**My question in short:**

Which data type can I use to get all entries sorted AND to be able to overwrite single entries?

**My question in long:**

I have a huge amount of point cloud models that I want to store and work with via Redis.
My `point cloud model` consists of three things:

- Unique id (stays the same)
- Point Cloud as a string (changes over time)
- Priority as an integer (changes over time)

Basically I would like to be able to do only two things with Redis. However, if I understand the documentation correctly, these are seen as benefits of two different data types, so I can't find a data type that exactly fits my use case. I hope, however, that I am wrong about this and that someone here can help me.

**Use case**:

- Get quick all models, all already sorted
- Overwrite/update a specific model

**Sorted Sets**

[image]
*Advantage*

- Get all entries in sorted order
- my model property `Priority` can be used here as a score, which determines the order.

*Disadvantage*

- No possibility to access a special value via a key and overwrite it.

**Hashes**:

[image]
*Advantage*

- Overwrite specific entry via `Key > Field`
- Get all entries via `Key`

*Disadvantage*

- No sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to just use two distinct data types:

- a hash with all the properties of your model, with the exception of the priority;
- a sorted set which allows to easily sort your collection and deal with the scores / priorities.

You could then link the two by storing each hash key (or a distinctive value which allows to reconstruct the final hash key) as the related sorted set member.

For example:

```bash
> HSET point-cloud:123 foo bar baz suppiej
> ZADD point-clouds-by-priority 42 point-cloud:123
```

You will keep all the advantages you mentioned, with no disadvantages at all.

Comment: Ok, but there I unfortunately still have the following problem, which I did not explain properly in the post. I want to have a sorted list of all my pointClouds, so I can access f.e. the property `PointCloud` of every pointcloud. So if I go your way, I get with `ZRANGE point-clouds-by-priority 0 -1` all references to the hashes. Then I have to query for every reference the property `PointCloud`. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @Perazim. While the performance should not be a concern here, you may also combine the `ZRANGE*` and the `HGET` commands into a single LUA script which will be [evaluated](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/eval-intro/) at the Redis server side.

Comment: `ZRange` and `HGET` did it for me. Later I'm gonna try it with LUA scripts :) Thanks!